# Is there any way to format an image like a artisteer header in joomla?

Tags: html, css, joomla

My artisteer template has a image in the header and on my joomla based webpage as the page width decreases (like on tablets/phones) the image stays the same size and the browser just displays the center of the image.

Is there anyway to duplicate this effect on an embedded image in my article or with some module extension.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Mate , Never worked with artisteer but i suggest you it's alternative TemplateToaster for future.